# Is there any way to change top color of setError in android(java)?

Tags: java, android, interface

How can i change color of the top line of setError?

I mean this
http://puu.sh/nOU5c/a53c58254b.png

Programatically or with xml is indifferent, the red color of the line doesn't match with my app color theme!

Thanks

Comment: can you post your xml layout file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change color associated with your View like this, programmatically:

```
yourView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(ActivityContext, R.color.Red));
```